# Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds 4-34 Homotopy and boundaries

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, manifolds, homotopy-theory

[image]

I'm trying to do part a. So far, I've tried rearranging the equalities, but nothing seems to pop out.  I think I have to use the definition of a boundary of a manifold and let some x be in the boundary and show it agrees with the definition, but I don't know how to do that. 
any help would be appreciated